# Returning multiple values from a looping thread without killing it in Java

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I am trying to implement a online ordering system-isch thing that will work through MySQL in Java.
Using MVC I am trying to implement a looping class that will continuously check for changes in a DB table that will hold orders when they arrive. Now for every order I get, i want to display this to a JFrame as a "box".

For this I am using a Callable thread that loops the Class called OrderCheck.java. This function is then called from the Controller which looks like this.

```
public ArrayList<Order> StartOrderChecking() {
    OrderCheck OCObj = new OrderCheck();
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); //We want one thread
    task = service.submit(OCObj);   //Submit the thread
    try {
            orderList = task.get();

        } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    return orderList;
}
```

And the thread function looks a little bit like this...

```
public ArrayList<Order> call() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            System.err.println("Thread looping");
            ConnectToDB();
            query = "SELECT * FROM mb_orders";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String order = rs.getString("order");
                String orderinfo = rs.getString("orderinfo");
                int phone = rs.getInt("phone");

                newOrder = new Order(ID,email,order,orderinfo,phone); //We create and Order object
                orderList.add(newOrder); // This is my Arraylist that i want to return back to the view
                return orderList;
            }

            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            Thread.sleep(Time);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

The code simply loops until the program is terminated, for every 3rd second i check the DB if any new orders have arrived, if so storing them in a ArrayList and hen returning. 
Now the issue I am facing is that this implementation will only return once and then the thread will die, I want to somehow get continous dataupdates from the DB back to the Controller which then sends it back to the View so that I can display it in my GUI.

Any help is appreciated!

I can fully understand if my implementation is faulty and would accept any help to fix the implementation. I can now see that the issue is also how to continuously move the data from Controller to view without halting the whole program.

Regards

EDIT: Adding this because I felt that some clarification on the issue was needed.
I am using a MVC patter which in terms mean that I have 3 different abstractions, M stands for the Model abstraction which holds all seperate classes relating to the application, V stands for the View abstraction which is only going to have the code which the user can see and calls from user interaction. C stands for the Controller abstraction which gets calls from user interractions from the View and further distributes them to the right Class in the Model.

Now In my case I have a GUI that is created in a EDT in the View abstraction and the above SQL-Conituous-loop-feth-connection-class-thing is in the Model(ofcourse). I would like a way for this thread to somehow continue looping, whilst continuously fetching this ArrayList that contains all relevant orders from the SQL database and then sending them back to the Controller OR! (and this sounds better if it is possible), refreshing the main GUI that is in the View Abstraction directly from the looping thread.

So simply put:
- How do i implement a looping thread that can update my GUI that exists in the View so that relevant new orders are displayed in the main frame.

Below is how, and where i create the GUI and also how I call the Controller to start the thread:

```
public class View extends JFrame {
. 
. 
.
public View(String UN) {
    setTitle("ExpressFood Admin Panel: " + UN);
    setSize(800, 800);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Centered JFrame...
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Panel Setup
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    add(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    JMenuBar mainMenu = new JMenuBar();
    //Build test menu if needed...
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
    mainMenu.add(menu);
    setJMenuBar(mainMenu);
}
.
.
private void StartSim() throws SQLException, Exception { 
//Show the main frame to the user
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame mainFrame = new View(UN);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
orderList = controller.StartOrderChecking(); //Call to Controller for OrderCheck.java
}
```

The followin code is how I am calling the OrderCheck.java Class from the Controller:

```
public ArrayList<Order> StartOrderChecking() {
    OrderCheck OCObj = new OrderCheck();
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(OCObj, 1, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    orderList = OCObj.sendToEDTForUpdate();
    return orderList;
}
```

Comment: Where there any exceptions thrown?  An exception will cause the thread to die. The only possible issue could be with database connection not releasing or reestablishing.

Comment: No exceptions are thrown, The program in its state works but the continuous updating whenever a DB entry is added/removed is something which the program is not able to do

Comment: Notice the thread is returning, this would break the while loop.

Comment: At first I was going to post a snarky comment about doing your own work, then I realized that you did, mostly, and you need help with fixing a specific, reproducible issue whose cause you even know and explain, along with providing the relevant code. Good question. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Much appreciated! I am very new to programming in general and the issue is yet to be fixed, but I am getting some very valuable help!

Comment: The `return` inside of the `while-loop`will exit the thread after  the first execution. i.e.`return orderList;`

Comment: The view should be dumb, it should receive data to display, not ask for it. This is key to the MVC system - although MVP is more popular for a non-template based GUI applications. So your view should not be telling the controller to start work, the controller should tell _it_ to display something. It _is_ the controller after all...

Comment: @BoristheSpider That is interesting, because what I learnt in my Object oriented programming class was that the View is sort of the main flow of the program, It tells the controller to do something and the controller distributes the task to the corresponding Class or function. But your intuition sounds alot better.. Should I have it so that the controller is the main flow?

Answer (score 0):

Do not return the order. You already know how to create a thread pool and execute threads in it, so every time database query returns an order, simply create an async thread to execute that order. And only quit from your infinite loop when your program is shutting down.

Comment: Nope. Everything that happens with the GUI **must** happen on the EDT. You cannot process this in an async thread.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `ExecutorService`, you need a `SwingWorker`.

Lets examine how a `SwingWorker` works:

```
new SwingWorker<Void, Order>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //publish a chunk, this will get picked up for processing
        publish(newOrder);
        //we need to return null as the method is Void
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Order> chunks) {
        //process new chunks on the EDT
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        //Thread is done, probably a problem
    }
};
```

So there's a few things you have to understand about Swing. It's not threadsafe, so you must only ever access Swing components on the EDT. This is extremely important.

So, what a `SwingWorker` does is that the `doInBackground` method runs on some background thread. When this method finishes, the `done` method is called **on the EDT**. And when you call `publish` in the `doInBackground` method then the published object is passed to the `process` method which is again, **called on the EDT**.

So, unless you know what you are doing, you should be used the constructs already in place for synchronization between worker threads and the EDT.

So, in your example:

```
new SwingWorker<Void, Order>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            System.err.println("Thread looping");
            ConnectToDB();
            query = "SELECT * FROM mb_orders";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String order = rs.getString("order");
                String orderinfo = rs.getString("orderinfo");
                int phone = rs.getInt("phone");

                final Order newOrder = new Order(ID, email, order, orderinfo, phone);
                publish(newOrder);
            }

            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            Thread.sleep(Time);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Order> chunks) {
        for (Order chunk : chunks) {
            //display chunk
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        //Thread is done, probably a problem
        try {
            get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Now, you need to ensure that you **never** have an empty catch block. You **must** process the exception somehow - log it or show it.

In fact empty catch blocks are a reason for an official verbal warning at many software houses.

Comment: I can see how this would be a possible solution, could you please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would suggest to do

1. Create a Runnable, execute db query code in there and after getting Order send those over to display on gui and display code should be in EDT.

   class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
       List<Order> orders = connectToDBAndGetOrders();
       sendToEDTForUpdate(orders);
       return ;
   }

   private void sendToEDTForUpdate(final List<Order> orders) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               for(Order order : orders) {
                   //display on gui
               }
           }
       });
   }

   private List<Order> connectToDBAndGetOrders() {
       String query;
       Statement stmt;
       ResultSet rs;
       List<Order> orderList;
       Connection con;
       try {
           con = ConnectToDB();
           query = "SELECT * FROM mb_orders";
           stmt = con.createStatement();
           rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
           orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
           while (rs.next()) {
               int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
               String email = rs.getString("email");
               String order = rs.getString("order");
               String orderinfo = rs.getString("orderinfo");
               int phone = rs.getInt("phone");

               Order newOrder = new Order(ID,email,order,orderinfo,phone); //We create and Order object
               orderList.add(newOrder); // This is my Arraylist that i want to return back to the view
               return orderList;
           }

           stmt.close();
           con.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           //exception handling
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Schedule this Runnable to excute every 3 second or as you want. Please node there are two methods scheduleAtFixedRate and scheduleWithFixedDelay, I would suggest to use scheduleWithFixedDelay.

   ```
   ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
   MyRunnable c = new MyRunnable();

   executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(c, 1, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   ```

**EDIT Sample Complete Code**

There is no db connectivity. Off course this is not production ready code just to show my thought process,

```
package thread.executor;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame("Background Fetching");

                Controller controller = new Controller(frame);
                controller.startFetchingOrder();
                frame.setSize(600, 600);

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        } );

    }

    public MyFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        getContentPane().add(new JButton("Fixed"));
    }

    public void addNewButton(String text) {
        getContentPane().add(new JButton(text));
        validate();
    }


    static class Controller {

        ScheduledExecutorService executor;
        MyFrame view;

        public Controller(MyFrame view) {
            this.view = view; 
        }

        public void startFetchingOrder() {
            executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            MyRunnable c = new MyRunnable(this);

            executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(c, 1, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        public void stopFetchingOrder() {
            if(executor != null)
                executor.shutdown();
        }

        public void sendToEDTForUpdate(final List<Order> orders) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(Order order : orders) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  adding new order "+order.getId());
                        view.addNewButton(""+order.getId());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        Controller controller;

        public MyRunnable(Controller controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<Order> orders = connectToDBAndGetOrders();
            controller.sendToEDTForUpdate(orders);
            return ;
        }

        static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

        private List<Order> connectToDBAndGetOrders() {
            List<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>();

            int count = (int)(5 * Math.random());

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Order order = new Order((counter.incrementAndGet()*1000)+i, null, null, null, 0);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  got new order "+order.getId());
                list.add(order);
            }

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  returningOrders "+list.size());
            return list;
        }
    }
}

class Order {
    int id;

    public Order() { 
        id = 0;
    }
    public Order(int Id, String email, String order, String orderInfo, int phone) {
        this.id = Id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will start by in all honesty telling that this is one of my first times working with threads on Java, I have only ever done this on Erlang before. Now I have read about EDT and I have implemented my GUI so that it is invoked on the EDT. 
Keeping in mind that I have a MVC structure:
What I am not understanding is how this will solve the issue of the thread not dying and also how through this I will be able to update the GUI.

For instance, how can i access the GUI(that was invoked from the view class) in my Model so that changes can be made. 
Secondly, where do I add the schedule?

Comment: @hassan-nazar : **how this will solve the issue of the thread not dying** : `executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay` will keep executing first argument (MyRunnable) forever with specified delay in between (3 sec). There should be a call to `executor.shutdown()` when you want to stop checking DB for new orders.  **also how through this I will be able to update the GUI** - Probably you would want to pass your controller to MyRunnable so that it can request view to update after fetching orders from DB.

Comment: Please check additional code in my post, It contain complete program that you can run on your side and change as you see feasible for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get a clear picture of what you are trying to do. 
Creating a thread to continuously query a database to update a list that is presented to some view.

I notice that you are call `return` inside the `while-loop`, which is exiting the method.

I suggest that you use a `newSingleThreadExecutor`, instead of `newFixedThreadPool`, along with a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Use a get method the retrieve update orderList.

```
private  CopyOnWriteArrayList<Order> orderList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
ExecutorService service = null;
```

...

```
public void StartOrderChecking() {
    OrderCheck OCObj = new OrderCheck();
    if(service.isShutdown()){
        service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }else{
        service.shutdownNow();
        service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    service.execute(OCObj);
}
```

...

```
public ArrayList<Order> getOrderList() {
    ArrayList rtnList = new ArrayList();
    for(Order order : orderList){
        rtnList.add(order);
    }
    return rtnList;
}
```

...

```
private class OrderCheck implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.err.println("Thread looping");
                ConnectToDB();
                query = "SELECT * FROM mb_orders";
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                orderList.clear();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                    String email = rs.getString("email");
                    String order = rs.getString("order");
                    String orderinfo = rs.getString("orderinfo");
                    int phone = rs.getInt("phone");

                    newOrder = new Order(ID, email, order, orderinfo, phone); //We create and Order object
                    orderList.add(newOrder); // This is my Arraylist that i want to return back to the view
                }

                stmt.close();
                con.close();
                Thread.sleep(Time);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log something
        }
    }

}
```

Just replace `OCObj.sendToEDTForUpdate()` with `getOrderList`

```
public ArrayList<Order> StartOrderChecking() {
    OrderCheck OCObj = new OrderCheck();
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(OCObj, 1, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    orderList = controller.getOrderlist();
    return orderList;
}
```

Hope this help and good luck programming

Comment: For a MVC pattern `OrderCheck` would be part of the "model" and `StartOrderChecking` &  `getOrderList` would be part of the "controller"